# GLSL/GL2.1 Lighting: Transforming to Eye Space

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

So, it helps to transform everything to eye space before doing lighting calculations? I'm having trouble with the transforming part. I've got the normals transformed right, but when I apply translations (when the object is not in the center of the world coordinate system), the lighting remains exactly the same.

I have confirmed that there are no problems with any C++ code.
I will paste my shaders...

QUESTION: I would like to know what I'm not transforming right, and how I'm supposed to transform it.

vertex shader...

```
const int MAXLIGHTS = 4;

uniform int lightcount;
uniform vec4 lPositions[MAXLIGHTS];

//V = transformed vertex
//N = transformed normal
//E = eye vector
//L = vector from vertex to light
varying vec3 V, N, E, L[MAXLIGHTS];

void main()
{
    int lcount = lightcount > MAXLIGHTS ? MAXLIGHTS : lightcount;

    V = vec3(gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex);

    N = gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal;

    E = normalize(-V);

    for(int i = 0; i < lcount; i++)
    {
        L[i] = gl_NormalMatrix * normalize(vec3(lPositions[i] - gl_Vertex));
    }

    gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
    gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

fragment shader...

```
const int MAXLIGHTS = 4;

uniform int lightcount;
uniform vec4 lDiffuses[MAXLIGHTS];
uniform vec4 lAmbients[MAXLIGHTS];

varying vec3 V, N, E, L[MAXLIGHTS];
uniform bool justcolor;

void main()
{
    if(justcolor)
    {
        gl_FragColor = gl_Color;
        return;
    }
    int lcount = lightcount > MAXLIGHTS ? MAXLIGHTS : lightcount;

    vec4 ambient;
    vec4 diffuse;
    vec4 specular = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    vec4 color = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    vec3 H;
    float NL;
    float NH;

    for(int i = 0; i < lcount; i++)
    {
        specular = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

        ambient = lAmbients[i];

        NL = dot(N, L[i]);
        diffuse = lDiffuses[i] * max(NL, 0.0);

        if(NL > 0.0)
        {
            H = normalize(E + L[i]);
            NH = max(0.0, dot(N, H));
            specular = pow(NH, 40.0) * vec4(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1.0);
        }

        color += gl_Color * (diffuse + ambient) + specular;
    }

    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Comment: What am I supposed to do that I'm not doing to transform my variables into eye space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
L[i] = gl_NormalMatrix * normalize(vec3(lPositions[i] - gl_Vertex));
```

This code only makes sense if `lPositions` is in *model* space. And that's highly unlikely.

The general way this works is that you pass light positions in eye space, so there's no need to transform them.

Also, L and E are entirely superfluous. You will get more accurate results by computing these in the fragment shader. The computations are quite simple and cheap, and since you need to renormalize them (which you don't do) in the fragment shader anyway, you're not really getting anything.

L is just the eye-space light position - the eye-space surface position. E is just the direction from the eye to the position, which is the normalized negation of the eye-space surface position.

Comment: How can I pass them in in eye space? I need to renormalize L and E? Are their lengths changed by interpolation? If I don't pass them in in eye space, is it possible to transform them to it in my shaders?

Comment: @MilesRufat-Latre: You transform them into eye space and stick them in a uniform. Presumably, you keep your lights in world-space. So use your camera matrix to transform them to eye-space. This will require that you pull the matrices out of OpenGL and do some vector/matrix multiplication on your own.

Comment: @MilesRufat-Latre: Interpolation doesn't know or care if a value is a normalized vector direction. It interpolates each of the components of the vector independently of the rest. So it will not be normalized when it gets finished.

Comment: What does the camera matrix consist of, if not simply gl_ModelViewMatrix? Is there any way to transform my data in the shaders instead of in my C++?

Comment: @MilesRufat-Latre: Why would you want to do it in the shader? The eye-space light position will be the same for every vertex. It's just a waste of time. The model-view matrix, as the name suggests, transforms from model-space to view/eye/camera space. You probably use gluLookAt or something similar to define where your world space is; that's the matrix you need to transform your lights by.

Comment: I use glTransformf and glRotatef...should I be using something else?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4943/discussion-between-miles-rufat-latre-and-nicol-bolas)

Comment: Nicol Bolas is completely right, that you should do most of the calculations in the fragment shader. I already told you this in the other posts.

Answer (score 3):

Eye space is the space your scene is transformed to right before it goes through the projection matrix. That's what `ftransform()` conveniently wraps (by this I meant the full path from model space through eye space (modelview transform) to clip space (projection transform)).

The modelview matrix contains the full transformation from object local to eye space. However your lights will not be in (each) object's local space, but in world space. So we're dealing with two distinct transformations here:

- Object local to World – this is *model* part of modelview
- World to Eye – this is the *view* part

So technically it was possible to transform both lights and object vertices in the vertex shader, by supplying the decomposed modelview as model and view uniform matrix inputs. Then you'd transform light positions by just the view part, and object's vertices by model, then view part. But I recommend not doing it that way. The computing resources of the shader units should be reserved to computations that have a different result for each vertex input. Light position transformations don't do this.

Instead you should pre-transform your light positions to eye space before passing them to the shader (uniforms). So how to do this. First I strongly suggest you rid yourself of the old OpenGL matrix manipulation functions (glRotate, glTranslate, glScale, … and GLU helpers like gluPerspective, …). Things get easier without them, plus they have been removed from later OpenGL versions.

So how to do it then. Say you've got a matrix library, like GLM, but any other will work, too. To render your scene you follow about that scheme (Python-like pseudocode)

```
render_scene:
    projection_matrix = Matrix.Perspective(…)
    view_matrix = Matrix.LookAt(…)

    light_positions = []
    for i, light in enumerate(scene.lights):
        if i > MAX_LIGHTS:
             break
        light_positions.append( view_matrix * light.position )

    glUniform3fv(glGetUniformLocation("lPositions"), light_positions)

    for object in scene.objects:
        obj_modelview = view_matrix * object.transform
        # This is using deprecated functionality
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); glLoadMatrix(obj_modelview)
        object.draw()
```

As you can see, the lights are "manually" transformed to eye space by use of the view_matrix whereas object's vertices are not touched on the GPU, but the parameters for shader set for the drawing.

Comment: "That's what ftransform() conveniently wraps." No, it doesn't. `ftransform` transforms all the way to clip-space. The spec is quite clear on this: the proper way to use it is with this statement: `gl_Position = ftransform();`

Comment: @NicolBolas: Actually I meant the whole pipeline right through to clip space, though I admit I did formulate it quite unhappy.

Comment: I think you mean 'Object local to world' instead of 'Object local to Eye' in your first bullet point.

Comment: @Mortennobel: Right you are. Will fix